# Regular Expression to verify data format in Netezza DB

Tags: regex, netezza

I am validation column in Netezza DB to make sure all the data in correct format. The sample data is in this format `'2014-01-21 04:43:00'`.

Is it possible to validate this using default function in Netezza?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appreciate you response.

Able to come up with following solution with you support.

```
select SQLEXT.regexp_like('2014-01-21 04:43:00','\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$')
```

Answer (score 2):

As @ScottMcG mentioned, you can use the SQL Extension Toolkit to use regular expressions.  This example will return a `boolean` validation of the pattern match.

`select sql_functions.admin.regexp_like('2014-01-21 04:43:00','\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$')`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the isdate UDF provided with the included INZA package. It's a boolen function that checks the input str to test against a format that you supply.

You have to install it into the database that you want to use it in, like this

```
[nz@netezza examples]$ pwd
/nz/extensions/nz/nzlua/examples
[nz@netezza examples]$ ../bin/nzl -d testdb isdate.nzl

Compiling: isdate.nzl
####################################################################
UdxName      =  isdate
UdxType      =  UDF
Arguments    =  VARCHAR(40),VARCHAR(40)
Result       =  BOOL
Dependencies =  INZA.INZA.LIBNZLUA_3_2_0
NZUDXCOMPILE OPTIONS: (--replbyval --nullcall --unfenced --mem 2m)
CREATE FUNCTION
[nz@netezza examples]$ nzsql -d testdb -c "select isdate('2014-01-21 04:43:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');"
 ISDATE
--------
 t
(1 row)

[nz@netezza examples]$ nzsql -d testdb -c "select isdate('2014-01-21 44:43:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS');"
 ISDATE
--------
 f
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case I don't have privilege to install. So, is there any other option than this?

Comment: Other than the regexp functions available in the SQL Extension Toolkit, which is also included, but must also be installed by an administrator, I don't know of a way to do this efficiently in Netezza with a UDF, which would have to be installed. Sorry!